# O(1) algorithm to get approximate number that is larger as a binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics

Ideally I need a to calculate the binomial coefficient ${p \choose n}$. But since the fastest algorithm to do this is an $\mathcal{O}(n)$ algorithm I would look to do something different. I don't really care for the exact number as long as it is reasonably close and is at least equal or larger then the actual number. My number should be within a factor of 2 of actual binomial coefficient. Is there an $\mathcal{O}(1)$ way to compute such a number?

Comment: What is $n$ here?

Comment: @orlp the lower number of the binomial coefficient.

Comment: The answer has size $\Omega(n)$, in general.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Not necessarily. Since OP is interested in approximations within a factor of two, perhaps he is interested in a $\log_2$ approximation with absolute error less than 1 of the true value.